# Root of the sum of two squared twin primes multiplied by $2*\pi$

Tags: number-theory

Let be p(n) and p(n)+2 two twin primes.

Let be $\lfloor x\rfloor$ the floor function.

Consider now:

$A=\lfloor{(\sqrt{p(n)^2+(p(n)+2)^2}}*2*\pi\rfloor$

I found that A is prime for $p(n)=41$ and $p(n)+2=43$. In this case A=373.
Are plenty of A which are primes? Second question: as you can see $373-43-41=17^2$. So I wonder if there are other A's such that A is prime and $A-p(n)-p(n)-2$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Plenty is a bit vague.

Comment: @Peter are there other A's which are primes?

Comment: We don't even know if there are infinitely many twin primes, so this is probably not going anywhere.

Comment: What is the motivation for this question? At any rate, a three-line Maple script finds many of these, $41, 197, 269, 1667, \ldots$.

Comment: @Peter@Travis@Thomas Andrews I edited the question and added a second question

Comment: Most of the time, this is going to be $$\left\lfloor \sqrt 2 \pi\left(2(p(n)+1)+\frac{1}{p(n)+1}\right)\right\rfloor.$$

Comment: $$\sqrt{p^2+(p+2)^2} = \sqrt{2p^2+4p+4}=\sqrt{2}\sqrt{(p+1)^2+1}$$ And, $$\sqrt{M^2+1}=M+\sqrt{M^2+1}-M=M+\frac{1}{\sqrt{M^2+1}+M}\approx M+\frac1{2M}$$ The last is actually slightly larger, so the floor will will usually be $\left\lfloor\sqrt{2}\pi\left(2(p+1)+\frac{1}{p+1}\right)\right\rfloor$ but sometimes be one less.

Comment: aka $A=\lfloor\pi\sqrt{8(p(n))^2+16 p(n)+16}\rfloor$

Answer (score 0):

The following PARI/GP code reveals two solutions satisfying also the second condition :

```
? forprime(p=1,10^9,q=p+2;if(ispseudoprime(q)==1,a=truncate(sqrt(p^2+q^2)*2*Pi);
if(ispseudoprime(a)==1,if(issquare(a-p-q)==1,print1(p," ")))))
41 106661
?
```

I do not have a heuristic for finite or infinite many solutions , but apparently solutions are rare.

Comment: $$2168546981$$ is the third solution

Comment: And the fourth is $$4549152371$$